# Show that $X$ and $Y$ are closed linear spaces and $\overline{X+Y}=E$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

**Question:** Let $E=l^{1}$ (the space of real, absolutely convergent series) and define
$$X=\{x=(x_{n})_{n\geq1}\in E:x_{2n}=0 \ \forall n\geq 1\}$$
and
$$Y=\{y=(y_{n})_{n\geq1}\in E:y_{2n}=\frac {1}{2^{n}}y_{2n-1} \ \forall n\geq 1\}.$$
Show that $X$ and $Y$ are closed linear spaces and $\overline{X+Y}=E$.

**My attempt:** I've proved that $\overline{X}=X\subset E$ and also $\overline{Y}=Y\subset E$. I also proved that $X$ and $Y$ are convex spaces. I defined $Z=\{z=x+y: x\in  X \text{ and } y\in Y\}$. And I tried to build new subsequences in order to prove the equality required. However I'm struggling with this. Would someone help me?

P.S. My doubt is different from this other question I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099712/two-disjoint-convex-closed-sets-that-cannot-be-separated-by-a-closed-hyperplane)

Comment: please write the whole question here or simply put the gist of it and what you have tried and why it wouldn't work.

Comment: ok @WillM. I'll do it. However they say that the question already exists. But my doubt is in other part of the same question.

Comment: Then put the link to the other question and say why it is different.

Comment: If you had a _dense sequence_ in $E$ and that sequence belonged to $\overline{X+Y},$ then its span would also belong to $\overline{X+Y}$ and so would its closure begin the latter subsepace a closed subspace. There are some obvious candidates for dense sequences in $E.$

Comment: Unfortunately, for me isn't obvious, but thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Consider $e_i$ the sequences with zeroes everywhere except position $i$th which has a one. Then, $e_i = x + y$ where $y = 2^i e_{i-1}$ (so that the position $i$th of $y$ is a one, the position $(i-1)$th is a $2^i$ and everywhere else is zero) and $x = -2^i e_{i-1}$ (to "cancel out the bad index").

Comment: And the sequence $e_i$ is dense for a sequence $(a_n)$ belongs to $\ell^1$ if and only if the series $(a_i e_i)$ converges in $\ell^1$ to $(a_n).$ (Think about this, write it out as a lemma, it will enligthen you.)

Comment: wow, ok. Thanks for all hints. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write a general $z \in \ell^1$ as $z = x+y$ with $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. Then since $x_{2n} = 0$, it is easy to see that the only candidates are:
$$\begin{cases}
y_{2n} = z_{2n},\\
y_{2n-1} = 2^nz_{2n},
\end{cases} \qquad\qquad \begin{cases}
x_{2n} = 0,\\
x_{2n-1} = z_{2n-1}-2^nz_{2n},
\end{cases}$$

Now, if $z$ is a finitely-supported sequence, then the above relations yield well-defined elements $x\in X$ and $y \in Y$ such that $z =x+y$.

Therefore
$$\text{finitely-supported sequences} \subseteq X+Y \implies \ell^1 = \overline{\text{finitely-supported sequences}} \subseteq \overline{X+Y} \subseteq \ell^1$$
so $\overline{X+Y} = \ell^1$.

This exercise is interesting because $X+Y \ne \ell^1$, which means that $X+Y$ is a sum of two closed subspaces but it is not closed.

Namely, if we take $z = \left(\frac1{n^2}\right)_n \in \ell^1$ then the above relations yield
$$\begin{cases}
y_{2n} = \frac1{4n^2},\\
y_{2n-1} = \frac{2^{n-2}}{n^2},
\end{cases} \qquad\qquad \begin{cases}
x_{2n} = 0,\\
x_{2n-1} = \frac1{(2n-1)^2} - \frac{2^{n-2}}{n^2},
\end{cases}$$
which are not $\ell^1$-sequences so $z \notin X+Y$.

Comment: Wow, perfect!!! You built the set of sequences I was trying to build. Thanks very much. 
Just one doubt: What "finitely-supported sequences" mean? My mother tongue isn't English. If you mean support, for example, this set $ \omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n=\{x\in \omega: u(x)\neq 0\}$ we didn't studied this subject yet.

Comment: @180110888 Yes, a support of a sequence $x \in \ell^1$ would be the set $\{n \in \Bbb{N} : x_n \ne 0\}$. Finitely-supported sequences would be those with only finitely many nonzero elements. It is known that those are dense in $\ell^1$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for you help. :D